# Getting snapshot of process before it terminates

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu

I'd like to be execute a command-line and get a snapshot of its `/proc` tree. The point is to find out as much as possible about the process.

One potential problem is that the process might terminate before I finish copying stuff. Any suggestions how to get around this?

Here's what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# run command line and copy it's /proc tree to /tmp/proctree
# Example: copy_proc.py ls -l

import sys, os, shutil, subprocess as sp

if __name__=='__main__':
  f=open('/dev/null', 'w')
  p = sp.Popen(sys.argv[1:],stdout=f, stderr=f)
  if not os.path.exists('/tmp/proctree'):
    os.makedirs('/tmp/proctree')
  for f in os.listdir('/proc/'+str(p.pid)):
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/proc',f), '/tmp/proctree/'+f)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Every symbolic link is also a file.
2. `for f in os.listdir(path): do_something_with(f)` is wrong unless you are your cwd is `path`.

Also, examine this snippet's output:

```
import os

base = "/proc/%d" % os.getpid()
for f in os.listdir(base):
    f = os.path.join(base, f)
    print "%-40s %5s %5s %5s" % (f, os.path.isfile(f), os.path.islink(f), os.path.isdir(f))
```

Now regarding the first part of the question. When the child process terminates, it becomes a zombie unless `wait(2)` is called for that child. This means that if you don't have a fancy `SIGCHLD` handler in your program, you can safely do whatever you want with your child's `/proc/<pid>` directory before `wait(2)` is called.

You can also try sending `SIGSTOP` to your child, making your desired snapshot, and then sending `SIGCONT`.

Comment: good point, isfile/isdir actually seem to work as expected, I had a bug in `isfile` line

Comment: Hm...I wonder if /proc/<pid>/maps gets cleared when process becomes a zombie. I'm getting it to be empty which is not what I expect